# Listen for when an HTML5 Audio element stops playing

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I need to call a function when an HTML5 audio element stops playing. Specifically the function will reset the seek bar and change the pause icon to a play icon.

Here's my JavaScript:

```
var audio = document.getElementById('audio');

audio.addEventListener('ended', stopAudio);

function stopAudio() {
    audio.stop();
    $('.play-pause .play').show();
    $('.play-pause .pause').hide();
}
```

.. only the code inside is not executing once called. The audio is playing successfully and ending successfully, it's just not calling my function. What am I missing?

Comment: The code looks OK to me. Are you sure it's not running? Perhaps try a console.log() or similar in stopAudio();

Comment: Does your `<audio>` element actually have `id="audio"`?  Otherwise it looks fine -- `ended` is the correct event name.  http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#htmlaudioelement look for "Event handler"

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using `getElementById` and passing `audio` when I think you mean to use `getElementsByTagName`, either that or you have the wrong id for the audio element.

Comment: Nope -- it's because I had `audio.stop();` when I needed `audio.stop;`. Got it working, using `getElementById`.

Answer (score 0):

I needed:

`audio.stop;`

Instead of...

`audio.stop();`

Which fixed it :)

Comment: You didn't need that line at all. The audio has already stopped, hence the `ended` event firing. Additionally, there doesn't even exist a method called "stop" on an audio element. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML Audio Element has no method `stop()`. The reason your event handler isn't "working" is because the line `audio.stop();` throws an error and nothing below it will execute.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like below in order to detect if your audio has ended. There is no way to detect if it has been stopped but you can detect if it has ended or been paused. If you are looking for the code for when it's paused you replace the "ended" with "pause"

```
document.getElementById('audio').addEventListener("ended",function() {

$('.play-pause .play').show();
$('.play-pause .pause').hide();
}
```